# Loop through a specific JS code from an Analytics tool library

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Here is the thing, I've got this following code that I want to upgrade :

```
ATTag.customVars.set({
  site: {
    "1": tc_vars["env_template"],
    "2": tc_vars["product_category"],
    "3": tc_vars["product_name"],
    "4": tC.internalvars.service_category_2,
    "5": tc_vars["service_name"],
    "6": tc_vars["user_type"],
    "7": tc_vars["user_contract"],
    "8": tC.internalvars.ow_guarantee,
    "9": tc_vars["user_age"],
    "10": tc_vars["user_postalcode"],
    "11": tc_vars["user_city"],
    "12": tc_vars["user_department"],
    "13": tc_vars["user_recipient"],
    "14": tc_vars["user_section"],
    "15": tC.internalvars.responsive,
    "16": tc_vars["user_profil_type"],
    "17": tc_vars["accessibilite_faciliti"]
    },
```

})

The thing is that I would like to build this "site" object after being checked to only keep the key/value pairs that have values and eliminate those which don't have any value.

One goal of the task is to keep the actual sequencing.

I've seen solution with the "for in" loop but it doesn't work in my case.

I'm a JS beginner, hope someone could help :)

Regards,

Coki

Comment: In object sequencing is not present. It will always sequence data in some random order. Only array have sequence order. No way to preserve the sequencing in object.

Comment: I don't know about order, but https://zellwk.com/blog/looping-through-js-objects/ - `Object.entries` might interest you. First looping through `Object.entries`, while creating an array of entries from which you can then create another object by using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

Answer (score 1):

Here's what works for me (your check on what does and does not constitute a value might vary):

```js
var siteObject = {
  "1": "example_value",
  "2": "example_value",
  "3": "example_value",
  "4": "example_value",
  "5": "example_value",
  "6": null
};


console.log(siteObject);

var siteObjectEntries = Object.entries(siteObject);
var newSiteObject = {};

for (const [key, value] of siteObjectEntries) {
  if (value != null)
    newSiteObject[key] = value;
}

console.log(newSiteObject);
```

And also, if you by any chance mean "sequencing" as keeping the names of the properties sequential, then here's updated code:

```js
var siteObject = {
  "1": "example_value_1",
  "2": "example_value_2",
  "3": "example_value_3",
  "4": null,
  "5": "example_value_5",
  "6": "example_value_6",
  
};


console.log(siteObject);

var siteObjectValues = Object.values(siteObject);
var newSiteObject = {};
var index = 1;
for (const value of siteObjectValues) {
  if (value != null)
    newSiteObject[index++] = value;
}

console.log(newSiteObject);
```